# Using Passport.js local signin with LoopBack 2

Tags: passport.js, loopbackjs, passport-local

I'd like to apply loopback-passport so that I have tried 'loopback-example-passport'.
I clone this repository and modify provider.json a bit. (Facebook id and secret...)
There's nothing more I have changed.
I succeeded to Facebook login but I was not able to login locally.
I can make a new ID by '/signup' page and I checked out in db.json.
However, when I tried to login with the account I just made up, they said "Invalid username/password or email has not been verified"

I think something wrong with the source but I couldn't figure it out.
Please help me with this issue!!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The username/password login is baked into the Loopback framework, so you don't really need Passport for this (It is there to allow third-party logins). Look at the documentation in here on the exact way for registering users and logging-in via the REST API:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Logging-in-users.html
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Registering-users.html